# How do you find out who favorited a question?

Tags: support, bookmarks

Everyone can see how many favorites a particular question has. And everyone can go to a specific user's profile to see what questions he or she favorited. But I see no way to find out who favorited any specific question - my own questions in particular are the ones that pique my curiosity. (An interest in seeing like-minded people and all that jazz.) Unless there's an angle I'm not trying, googling turns up zilch. Is there a built-in feature to find favoriters, and if not, is the absence of such deliberate (why)?

Comment: You may want to try using [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/s/1017/) on data.SE. Your user id is `11763`. Bear in mind however that the databases there are only updated once or twice a month.

Comment: @Theo: The SQL dumps are bimonthly, but not the kind that happens twice a month, rather they happen once every two months.

Comment: @Asaf: Thanks. I didn't bother to check (I would have understood bimonthly). My point was rather that the databases are somewhat out-of-date most of the time...

Comment: @Theo: Quite understood. I was specific since bimonthly is an ambiguous term. I also understood that point you tried making about data.SE being almost always out-of-date, and was just trying to support it by strengthening your case. :-)

Comment: @Asaf: Ah, I wasn't aware of that ambiguity. I might have used biweekly for twice a month, but now I find out that it is suffering from the same ambiguity. As [Obélix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obelix) would put it: *Ils sont fous, ces anglophones!* .@anon: sorry about the off-topic pings.

Comment: @Theo: Not a problem. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 11):

As pointed out in the comments, [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/28557/who-favorited-my-questions) will tell you want to know, but the data is typically a month or two behind.

There is no way to retrieve the same information on the site itself and that's currently by design.