# How can we conduct automated collaborator detection? Should we conduct it?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm curious if there is a way for me to easily find out who answers my questions the most/comments the most/upvotes the most/who I have upvoted the most/bookmarked the most.

Basically I would like to know which users I interact with the most and see if I can discern what topic(s) cause those interactions.

This could allow us to be more aware of who our collaborators in specific topics are which is something I'd be curious about since I notice for some posts the same group of usernames responding to my questions and would like to have a clear understanding of who all I'm interacting with.

Right now these communities aren't explicitly well defined but like I have a vague notion of the "complex analysis crew" and I imagine that there are probably subtler groups than that hiding in plainsight that have never been explicitly acknowledged.

Answer (score 20):

The data about voting is not publicly available, but for some things mentioned in your question, you can use [SEDE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info). I have created a [community wiki](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-wiki/info) answer where various queries can be collected.

- [Top answerers to my questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1548852/top-answerers-to-my-questions?userid=58294) and [Whose questions I answer most often?](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1548855/whose-questions-i-answer-most-often?userid=58294)
- [Top commenter on my posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1548859/top-commenter-on-my-posts?userid=58294) and [Whose posts I comment on the most](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1548860/whose-posts-i-comment-on-the-most?userid=58294)
- [Users with most bookmarks on my posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1548866/users-with-most-bookmarks-on-my-posts?userid=58294) and [Users with most bookmarks from me](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1548871/users-with-most-bookmarks-from-me?userid=58294). See also: [How do you find out who favorited a question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2739)
- If you want to see users posting useful answers in some topic, you can check top answerers in a specific tag. Every tag shows a [list of top users](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/real-analysis/topusers). But it is possible to write also various SEDE queries related to this. You might find some related queries in the chatroom where various stats are collected - just search for queries containing [tag](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?room=17403&q=query+tag) or [tagname](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?room=17403&q=query+tagname).
- The queries linked in this MathOverflow Meta post seem to be somewhat related, too: [Is it possible to search for posts/questions of an user $X$ commented on/answered by the user $Y$?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3266)

It might be worth mentioned that the queries below user the OP as an example - you can change the userid to yours (or the userid of any other user). See also: [What is my user id and how do I check it?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6598) on this meta and [What is my user ID?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98771) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: The availability of who bookmarks my posts, to me, seems like a violation of privacy; just as it would be a violation of privacy to ask  and get a response to "Who upvotes me the most?" or "Who downvotes me the most? " And remember, more for the OP, that a lot of users also bookmark very poor to ensure a way to follow up on closure or deletion.   I would encourage users to use search capabilities to research non-self-centric facts.

Comment: @amWhy Since you have brought up bookmarks as a privacy issue here, I will mention some related posts on [meta.se]: [Is seeing other people's favorites a privacy issue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94826) and [Can there be an option to keep your list of bookmarks private?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140778) (And I would not be surprised if there are other discussions related to this. In any case, this is probably for a separate discussion - at the moment, bookmarks are publicly displayed, there is even an option search for `inbookmarks:userid`.

Comment: Thanks for the added info, @Martin.  I just meant to note that I seemed like it could be problematic, potentially.  But I also want users to know, as explained in my first comment, that a handful of others' bookmarks of one's post is not necessarily a sign the posts they were quality posts.  That wasn't meant to you, but readers: just that bookmarks aren't equivalent to "likes".

Comment: Just to note, the posted links seem to be related to user:58294 (frogeyedpeas) and need adjustment to relate to somebody else, such as me

Comment: @Henry Yes, that's true - of course, userid of any user can be enter into the boxes with parameters. (Alternatively, you could simply edit the userid in the URL.) Posting those queries with *some* userid entered seemed to me a better option than leaving it empty - some users wouldn't know what to enter there and it might be unclear to them what the query actually does. (I have edited the post a bit - it is CW, so you should not hesitate to edit it further if needed.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak No problem. I put my note to reduce the chance of others repeating my mistake: I initially thought I was being stalked by frogeyedpeas, who I had never heard of

Comment: "The data about voting *are*..." :(  \*pouts\*